# Pandas DataFrame - Generate Semi-annual Period Index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, period

Currently, I can generate quarterly, monthly and yearly index by changing frequency in following code.

```
df['period_index'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.Date, freq='Q')
```

Is there a way to tweak `freq` and get semi annual index?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of a work-around if you use `date_range` first:

```
pd.PeriodIndex(pd.date_range(df.Date.min(), df.Date.max(), freq="6M"))
```